# Differentiability and continuity of derivative

Tags: analysis

I always thought that functions that are differentiable, have continuous derivative. IMO it was very natural, also there's "Mean value theorem" that I explained to myself with those assumptions. Recently, my friend gave me such example:
$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} & \textrm{for $x = 0$} \\ 0 & \textrm{for $x\not=0$}
\end{array} \right.$$
So how come, there can be incontinuous derivative and "Mean value theorem" be true without assumption that derivative is continous?

Comment: Personally, I'm not sure I understand how "Mean value theorem" is supposed to be true *with* continuous derviatives. Let's say $f$ is $C^\infty$. Why is the "Mean value theorem" true for $f$?

Comment: E.g. lets take function f such $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$, then from "Mean value theorem" we would assume that $f'(x) = -1$ for some $x \in (0, 1)$. However, with derivative $$f'(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
-2 & \textrm{for $x \in (0, 0.5)$} \\ 0 & \textrm{for $x \in (0.5, 1)$}
\end{array} \right.$$ we would get function that doesnt fit "Mean value theorem"

Comment: basically the reason why the mean value theorem is true is that if you have an extremal point the derivative is zero there. Your function $f$ would be not differentiable in $0.5$.

Comment: @MarcinMazur the example you're giving doesn't even work, as the derivative you've provided is not even defined at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, hence $f$ is not differentiable on $(0,1)$, which is one of the assumptions of the Mean Value Theorem

Comment: @MarcinMazur That function is not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem doesn't require the derivative to be continuous. Have you read a proof of the mean value theorem? You should not confuse it with implying the *intermediate* value theorem on the derivative, and even that that wouldn't make the derivative continuous. Indeed derivatives *always* satisfy the intermediate value property - this is [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Darboux%27s%20theorem%20is,interval%20is%20also%20an%20interval.).

The mean value theorem is proven as follows: let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be differentiable over the bounded interval $(a,b)$. Consider $r:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto f(x)(b-a)-x(f(b)-f(a))$. You can check that $r(a)=r(b)$ and that $r$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, continuous on $[a,b]$. By Rolle's theorem, $r'(\xi)=0$ for some $a<\xi<b$, but this is precisely the statement that: $$f'(\xi)(b-a)=f(b)-f(a),\,f'(\xi)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

This is not a proof that anywhere needs $r'$ or $f'$ to be continuous. Thinking about Rolle's theorem, it only intuitively needs the concept of a "turning point".